# How to load data into spinner from database in android

Tags: android, database, spinner

In my application there is a spinner to provide the users to select units so that the data from that particular unit should be randomly displayed.My spinner looks like this
    Unit-1
    Unit-2
    .
    .
    .
    Unit-25
if user selects unit-2 from the spinner there are 12 words in the unit-2 so that the words from that unit should be displayed in random.
I have created a table and stored in the database the columns are unit,word
i have stored in the following way in the table

### unit|word

```
1    bank
1    stack
1    over
1    flow
.     .
.     .
.     .
2    google
2    facebook
2    gmail
```

so on upto 25 units there are 12 words per each unit.
Now i should retrieve them and display them randomly 
How to write logic for this if user clicks unit-12 that particular units words only should be displayed.please help me to solve this 
Thanks in advance

Comment: Set a OnItemSelectedListener() in your Spinner and retrieve the word values from your database according to the Spinner item index the user clicked

Answer (score 0):

- Here is a sample that i use to populate the data from Sqlite to
  Spinner, You can customize this to your needs, remove the `SQLite`
  part if you don't need it - instead pass an array

---

In `onActivityCreated` call this method

---

```
setDataForCity();
```

---

**FunctionDefinition**::

```
private void setDataForCity() {
    DatabaseHandler mHelper;
    SQLiteDatabase db = null;
    Cursor mCursor = null;

    ArrayList<LinkedHashMap<String,String>> listCollection=new ArrayList<LinkedHashMap<String,String>>();
    LinkedHashMap<String, String> mapCollection;
    try {

        mHelper = new DatabaseHandler(getActivity());
        db = mHelper.getReadableDatabase();

        //QUERY:- select city_id,city_name,no_of_buffets,downloaded from city_mas
        mCursor = db.rawQuery("select " 
                +""+city_mas.COLUMN_CITY_ID+"," 
                +""+city_mas.COLUMN_CITY_NAME+"," 
                +""+city_mas.COLUMN_DOWNLOADED+" " 
                +"from " 
                +""+city_mas.TABLE_NAME_CITY_MAS+"", null);

        if(mCursor.moveToFirst()){
            do{                 
                mapCollection=new  LinkedHashMap<String,String>();
                mapCollection.put(city_mas.COLUMN_CITY_ID, mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(city_mas.COLUMN_CITY_ID)));
                mapCollection.put(city_mas.COLUMN_CITY_NAME, mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(city_mas.COLUMN_CITY_NAME)));
                mapCollection.put(city_mas.COLUMN_DOWNLOADED, mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(city_mas.COLUMN_DOWNLOADED)));
                listCollection.add(mapCollection);
            }while(mCursor.moveToNext());
        }

        AdpSearchCitySpinner adapter=new AdpSearchCitySpinner(getActivity(),listCollection);
        spnSearchByCity.setAdapter(adapter);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

    }finally{
        if(db!=null){
            if(db.isOpen()) db.close();
        }
        if(mCursor!=null){
            if(!mCursor.isClosed())mCursor.close();
        }
    }
}
```

---

**AdpSearchCitySpinner.java**

```
public class AdpSearchCitySpinner extends BaseAdapter {

    Context mContext;
    ArrayList<LinkedHashMap<String, String>> city;

    public AdpSearchCitySpinner(Context context, ArrayList<LinkedHashMap<String, String>> _listCollection) {
        super();
        this.mContext = context;
        city=_listCollection;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return city.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return city.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        LinkedHashMap<String, String> mapCollection=city.get(position);

        LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) mContext).getLayoutInflater();
        View row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.adp_search_city_spinner, parent, false);

        TextView city_id = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.city_id);
        TextView city_name = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.city_name);
        TextView downloaded_id = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.downloaded_id);

        city_id.setText(mapCollection.get(city_mas.COLUMN_CITY_ID));       
        city_name.setText(mapCollection.get(city_mas.COLUMN_CITY_NAME));
        downloaded_id.setText(mapCollection.get(city_mas.COLUMN_DOWNLOADED));

        return row;
    }   
}
```

**Hope this helps** !